# Images Not Displaying in Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have encountered an issue where the images in my image slideshow are not displaying properly. This issue was observed after adding a logo to the webpage. Prior to adding the logo, the images were displaying correctly. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

Problem Description:
The webpage contains an image slideshow with three images (Seil, Solseil, and Rigg).
Each image is wrapped in a div with the class slide.
The CSS for the slide class includes properties like display: none, position: absolute, and opacity: 0 with transitions.
The images have the correct URLs, and I have verified that they are accessible by directly accessing their URLs in a browser.

Relevant Code Snippets:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Image Slideshow</title>
<style>
  
    .slideshow-container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    
    .slide {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
     .slide.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }

 .slide img {
 width: 100%;
 eight: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 }

.gradient-overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 1%, transparent 35%);
z-index: 2; 
}
.tab-banners {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-end;
z-index: 99;
}

.tab-banner {
padding: 20px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #A4A4A4; /* Farge for inaktive bannere */
margin-bottom: 10px;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'Nunito Sans', 
}

.tab-banner.active {
margin-right: 30px;
color: white; /* Farge for den aktive bannen */
}

.tab-banner.inactive {
color: #A4A49B;
}

.text-section {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
right: 10px;
color: #fff;
text-align: right;
padding: 10px;
max-width: 400px;
z-index: 99; 
}

.text-section h1 {
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 35px;
font-family: 'Nunito Sans',
margin: 0;
color: white;
}

.text-section p {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 26px;
margin: 10px 0;
color:white;
}

.arrow-icon {
background-image: url('');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
margin-top: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
z-index: 100;
    }

.logo img {
width: 20%; 
height: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="logo">
    <img src="" alt="Logo">
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
    
    <div class="slide" id="seil">
        <img src="" alt="Seilbilde">
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="solseil">
        <img src="" alt="Solseilbilde">
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="rigg">
        <img src="" alt="Riggbilde">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-banners">
    <div class="tab-banner active" id="seil-banner">
        Seil
    </div>
    <div class="tab-banner" id="solseil-banner">
        Solseil
    </div>
    <div class="tab-banner" id="rigg-banner">
        Rigg
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-section">
    <h1 id="image-title">Tittel for valgt bilde/tab</h1>
    <p id="image-text">Dette er teksten som tilhører valgt tab/container.</p>
    <div class="arrow-icon" id="image-arrow"></div>
</div>

<script>
// script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    const banners = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-banner");
    const imageTitle = document.getElementById("image-title");
    const imageText = document.getElementById("image-text");
    const arrowIcon = document.getElementById("image-arrow");

    // Legg til tittel, tekst og lenke for hver slide
    const slideData = [
        {
            title: "Seil",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            link: "https://www.seil.no"
        },
        {
            title: "Solseil",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
            link: "https://www.solseil.no"
        },
        {
            title: "Rigg",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            link: "https://www.rigg.no"
        }
    ];

    // Funksjon for å oppdatere teksten og lenken basert på valgt slide
    function updateSlideInfo(slideIndex) {
        imageTitle.textContent = slideData[slideIndex].title;
        imageText.textContent = slideData[slideIndex].text;
        arrowIcon.setAttribute("data-link", slideData[slideIndex].link);
    }

    // Forhindrer standard klikkoppførsel på tab-bannere
    banners.forEach((banner, index) => {
        banner.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Forhindrer standard klikkoppførsel
            const tabId = banner.id.replace("-banner", "");
            banners.forEach((b, i) => {
                if (i === index) {
                    b.classList.add("active");
                    b.classList.remove("inactive");
                } else {
                    b.classList.add("inactive");
                    b.classList.remove("active");
                }
            });
            // Oppdater teksten for valgt slide
            updateSlideInfo(index);
            // Oppdater bildefremvisningen til valgt slide
            slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
                if (i === index) {
                    slide.classList.add("active");
                } else {
                    slide.classList.remove("active");
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // Legg til klikkfunksjonalitet for pilen
    arrowIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const link = this.getAttribute("data-link");
        if (link) {
            // Håndter hva som skal skje når pilen klikkes
            // Her kan du legge til lenken eller handlingen du ønsker
            window.location.href = link;
        }
    });

    // Initial visning (for eksempel Seil som standard)
    banners[0].classList.add("active");
    updateSlideInfo(0);
    slides[0].classList.add("active");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Expected Behavior:
When the webpage loads, it should display the first image (Seil) in the slideshow.
Clicking on different tabs (Seil, Solseil, and Rigg) should change the active image and display the corresponding image.

Current Behavior:
The webpage loads without displaying any of the images in the slideshow.
Clicking on the tabs changes the content of the image-title and image-text elements, but the images themselves remain hidden.

Additional Information:
I have already checked the following:
The URLs of the images are correct, and I can access the images directly by opening their URLs in a browser.
The console does not show any error messages related to the images.
The issue persists across different browsers and even in incognito mode.
I have removed the JavaScript portion of the code to ensure it is not the cause of the issue, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your code is complete like that i noticed that your slides all have the attribute "display:none" and you never reasign this. So all you should need is an active display property in the active slide, like this:

```
   .slide {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
     .slide.active {
        display: inline; //this is missing
        opacity: 1;
    }
```